# jquery .ajax submitting data from two forms on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two forms on a page.

**Form1 - Collect company data**

```
<form id="company">
    Company Name : input - text
    Address : input - text
    City : select from drop down using select2
    submit button
</form>
```

**Form 2 - add a city to the drop-down list of Form 1**

```
<form id="city">
    City Name :input - text ....
    State : select from drop down using select2 ...
    button : add city ....onClick do .ajax submit
</form>
```

The Form 2 (city) is used to add a missing city in the drop-down list of Form 1 (Company). The "add city" function uses .ajax.

When I do that, .ajax is submitting data from **Form 1** and **Form 2**. I am clearly specifying the two fields which are to be submitted. I am suspecting setting of one of the .ajax parameters is the reason for this behavior.  I will appreciate if someone can help me fix this issue.  jQuery code is given below.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "addCity",
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        name: $("#city_name").val(),
        state: $("#state").val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var messages = $('.messages');

        var successHtml = "success message ....";
        $(messages).html(successHtml);

      }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide valid HTML (inside the `<form>` elements)

Comment: Thanks for asking for the form elements.  The issue was with me using the same id - city_name in both forms.  The issue is sorted out now.